# How to manage Feign errors?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

We are using *Spring-boot* with *Spring-cloud* and *Spring-cloud-netflix* with *Spring-cloud-feign*.

We are creating our Gateway application that with the help of `Feign` will try to communicate with our `authentication` microservice in order to validate their credentials. Here you can see an example of our Feign `authentication` client:

```
@FeignClient(value="auth", configuration = AuthClientConfiguration.class)

public interface AuthClient {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/tokens", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   Single<Session> getSession(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token);
}
```

The question is, how we can deal with all the exceptions that could be raised by the client? I mean, how we can for example catch that a `NetworkException` or a `TimeoutException` has been thrown? We've defined our own `ErrorDecoder` but it appears that this "kind of listener" only works when the request has arrived and the response returned (in our case from `authentication` client). So, how we can manage this other exceptions?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error decoders are decoding HTTP error responses (500, 404, 401, etc...). Exceptions will bubble up in client calls, so using `try/catch` should work.

```
    try {
        return client.home();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: isn't there a more specific exception to catch?

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. It has worked, the point is that in order to reuse that code we have to include it around. What we've done is just created a new class that acts as a decorator and then it manages all the "common" Exceptions like Timeouts, etc